# How to get nth-child value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
</ul>
<div id='output'></div>
```

I have just read about nth-child in javascript and I got a small question: How can I print out the value of the nth-child in the output div? I do it like this and it returns [object HTMLDivElement]

```
var el=$("ul li:nth-child(2)").val();
  $('#output').text('The second child is: '+el[0]);
  console.log(el);
```

Comment: Only `<input>` elements have a meaningful `.value` property, represented as the `value` attribute: `<input value="some text">`. `.val()` is for grabbing value of the `.value` attribute. As some of the existing answers state, `.text()` will grab the text contained inside of an element (or without jQuery, you can access the `.textContent` property of a raw DOM node). `.html()` (and it's DOM counterpart `.innerHTML`) will grab the HTML markup inside the element if you need it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take the text value :

```
var el = $("ul li:nth-child(2)").text();
```

And output it like this :

```
 $('#output').text('The second child is: ' + el);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#output').text('The second child is ' + $("ul li:nth-child(2)").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
</ul>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the innerText of the li instead of the value which is not present in this case.

```js
var el=$("ul li:nth-child(2)");
  $('#output').text('The second child is: '+el[0].innerText);
  console.log(el[0].innerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>One</li>
 <li>Two</li>
 <li>Three</li>
 <li>Four</li>
</ul>
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: Why `innerText` instead of `.text()`?